# Determine cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability

Consider a random variable $X$ with mass function $p_{X}(x)$ given by:

$$P(X=k) =\frac{6k^2}{n(n+1)(2n+1)}, \quad k= 1, \dots, n$$
I want determine the cumulative distribution function of $X$

We know that

$$F_{X}(k)=P(X \leq k)= P\left(\bigcup_{k' \leq k} \{X=k' \} \right)=\sum_{k' \leq k} p_{X}(k')$$

In our case this looks something like

$$F_{X}(x)=P(X \leq k)=\sum_{k'=1}^{k} P(X=k')=\frac{6k'^2}{k'(k'+1)(2k'+1)}$$

But something I don't understand is if $k$ goes from one to $n$, how does this influence the final result. How can I conclude the answer? any suggestion will be welcome!

Comment: The denominator is not a function of $k$. So compute $\sum_{k=1}^\ell k^2$ and...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you got mixed up with the different indices. Note that $n$ is a fixed constant, so that $\mathbb{P}(X = k) \propto k^2$ and the other factors play the role of a normalization constant. In consequence, one has :
$$
\mathbb{P}(X \le k) 
   = \sum_{k'=0}^k \mathbb{P}(X = k') 
   = \frac{6}{n(n+1)(n+2)}\sum_{k'=0}^k k'^2 
   = \frac{k(k+1)(k+2)}{n(n+1)(n+2)}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your input, just a small question, doesn't the summation start from 1?

Comment: Yes, it does, indeed. Anyway, it doesn't change anything, because $P(X = 0) = 0$.